# Module scoped variables being changed without explicit assignment

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm quite confused with some variable scoping behavior I'm experiencing. Take the following sample module:

```
$script:intTemplate = 1

[xml]$script:xmlTemplate = @"
<test>
    <element>
    </element>
</test>
"@

function getvar {
    $myint = $script:intTemplate
    $myint++
    Write-output "Myint is $myint while intTemplate is $intTemplate"

    $myxml = $script:xmlTemplate
    $e = $myxml.CreateElement("MyChildElement")
    $myxml.SelectSingleNode("/test").AppendChild($e) |Out-Null
    $myxml.Innerxml.tostring()
    $script:xmltemplate.Innerxml.tostring()
}
```

Now importing that module are running `getvar` generates:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> getvar
Myint is 2 while intTemplate is 1
<test><element></element><MyChildElement /></test>
<test><element></element><MyChildElement /></test>
```

Further runs of getvar continue to add more and more child elements to $xmlTemplate while $intTemplate remains the same. I don't understand why $myXml is not always starting off with the simple test/element structure and, more to the point, how the script local $xmlTemplate variable appears to be getting changed while intTemplate does not.

Any assistance on figuring out what is going on here would be much appreciated.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand scope has nothing to do with you problem, when you write `$myInt=$script:intTemplate` you manipulate a value, so you copy the value. When you write `$myxml = $script:xmlTemplate` you manipulate a reference, so copying a reference, you work with the same underlying object. Just try `$script:intTemplate += 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! So some objects ([XML]) get passed by reference and others ([INT32]) get passed by value? Is there some documentation or way to tell how an arbitrary object type will get passed via an assignment operation? I presume [string] objects get passed by value, but what about all the other possible .NET object types?

After drinking the "everything's an object" KoolAid, this behavior seems a little arbitrary/confusing.

Comment: @davidski On the whole, the rules for PowerShell are the same as for .NET: value types are passed by value, and reference types by reference. For immutable types like `Int32` and `String`, the difference is not very important. For mutable types though, every variable assignment of a mutable value type like [`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.aspx) will create an independent copy, while a mutable reference type like [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) will all point to the same object instance.